# Setting Vuetify Circular Progress Bar value after uploading image to firebase store

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to show the progress bar after Firebase store image upload success. I am able to upload the image but **unable to sync the response status with progress bar**.
   Here is the code snippet I am trying, could you point out the error. Thanks

```
<template>
   <v-progress-circular
     :rotate="360"
     :size="100"
     :width="15"
     :value="value"
     color="teal"
   >
    {‌{ value }}
   </v-progress-circular>
</template>

export default {
    data: () => ({

    interval: {},
    value: 0,
    percent: 0,
}
```

I am trying to insert [Vuetify circular progress widget](https://codepen.io/pen/?&editors=111). During the the image upload  in `UploadTask.On` promise, even if I set the value as below the value field is not getting updated with current progress.

```
uploadTask.on(
    "state_changed",
    function(snapshot) {
      this.percent = snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes * 100;
      this.value = this.percent
```

Comment: Assuming the missing closing brackets are typo errors  and with your current code, you're problem might be in the `uploadTask.on` function. Could you please add more details/codes on the function or the whole JS/script part? Also your codepen example is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue using Emit Bus Feature of Vue

```
uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        function(snapshot) {
          this.percent = snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes * 100;
          this.percent = Number(this.percent.toFixed(3).slice(0, -1));
          EventBus.$emit("upload-progress", this.percent);
          console.log("Upload is " + this.percent + "% done");
        },
        function error(err) {},
        function complete() {
          console.log("Upload finished!!!!");
        }
      );
    },
```

and

```
mounted() {
    this.$validator.localize("en", this.dictionary);
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.value === 100) {
        return (this.value = 100);
      }
      EventBus.$on("upload-progress", percent => {
        this.value = percent;
      });
    }, 1000);
  },
```